# Why AWSS Glue connections need a VPC S3 endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a psql RDS on the same AWS account where I am trying to set up a glue connection to it. I used the RDS option and selected my existing RDS, then I set up the network to be the same vpc,subnet and security groups as my RDS is hosted on.

So when the connection is ready, I tested it. But I got an error about the subnet of the vpc not finding an S3 endpoint.

I know from reading the documentation that I have to create a VPC endpoint towards the S3 to work as a gateway. Which I can do

But why is an S3 endpoint needed for a JDBC connection? What does the S3 have to do with reaching a database if we are already in the same network/subnet and have the correct security group to reach it? At what point in a JDBC connection does it needs a gateway to S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up a Glue job, under the `Job details` tab in the `Advanced properties` section you have to specify things like `Script path`, `Temporary path` etc which point to S3 locations.  So the Glue job needs to be able to access S3.

When you associate a connection with your Glue job, it causes the Glue job to be run within the VPC specified in the connection.  So now your Glue job needs a way to connect to S3 (which is external to your VPC) from within the VPC .

From [this page of the Glue Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-connecting.html):

> To access Amazon S3 from within your VPC, a VPC endpoint is required.

Try adding an S3 gateway endpoint to your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) explains this:

> Many customers have legitimate privacy and security concerns about sending and receiving data across the public internet. Customers can address these concerns by using a virtual private network (VPN) to route all Amazon S3 network traffic through their own corporate network infrastructure. However, this approach can introduce bandwidth and availability challenges.
>
> VPC endpoints for Amazon S3 can alleviate these challenges. **A VPC endpoint for Amazon S3 enables AWS Glue to use private IP addresses to access Amazon S3 with no exposure to the public internet.** AWS Glue does not require public IP addresses, and you don't need an internet gateway, a NAT device, or a virtual private gateway in your VPC. You use endpoint policies to control access to Amazon S3. **Traffic between your VPC and the AWS service does not leave the Amazon network.**
>
> When you create a VPC endpoint for Amazon S3, any requests to an Amazon S3 endpoint within the Region (for example, s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com) are routed to a private Amazon S3 endpoint within the Amazon network. You don't need to modify your applications running on Amazon EC2 instances in your VPC—the endpoint name remains the same, but the **route to Amazon S3 stays entirely within the Amazon network, and does not access the public internet**.